# Using virt-install to install Ubuntu Server 18.04 but hangs

Tags: ubuntu, kvm, libvirt

The host machine is a Ubuntu Server 19.10 with no GUI. I've installed KVM and try to install a Ubuntu Server 18.04 virtual machine using the command

```
sudo virt-install \
    --name demo1 \
    --os-variant=ubuntu18.04 \
    --ram=4096 \
    --vcpus=8 \
    --network bridge=br0 \
    --graphics none \
    --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/demo1.img,bus=virtio,size=16 \
    --location /home/ubuntu/virtualization/ubuntu-18.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso \
    --extra-args console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial
```

However, it hangs indefinitely. It first prompted (too much information, I cut part of it due to character limit):

```
Starting install...
Retrieving file vmlinuz...                                                                                                                      | 8.0 MB  00:00:00
Retrieving file initrd...                                                                                                                       |  55 MB  00:00:00
Allocating 'demo1.img'                                                                                                                          |  16 GB  00:00:00
Connected to domain demo1
Escape character is ^]
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.15.0-76-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-029) (gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)) #86-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 17:24:28 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 4.15.0-76.86-generic 4.15.18)
[    0.000000] Command line: console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial text
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x7, context size is 832 bytes, using 'compacted' format.
[    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009fbff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009fc00-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000f0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000007ffd8fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007ffd9000-0x000000007fffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b0000000-0x00000000bfffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed1c000-0x00000000fed1ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000feffc000-0x00000000feffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fffc0000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000017fffffff] usable
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[    0.000000] SMBIOS 2.8 present.
[    0.000000] DMI: QEMU Standard PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009), BIOS 1.12.0-1 04/01/2014
[    0.000000] Hypervisor detected: KVM
[    0.000000] e820: last_pfn = 0x180000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000000] x86/PAT: Configuration [0-7]: WB  WC  UC- UC  WB  WP  UC- WT
[    0.000000] e820: last_pfn = 0x7ffd9 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000000] found SMP MP-table at [mem 0x000f59f0-0x000f59ff]
[    0.000000] Scanning 1 areas for low memory corruption
[    0.000000] Using GB pages for direct mapping
[    0.000000] RAMDISK: [mem 0x7c85f000-0x7ffcffff]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
[    0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 0x00000000000F59B0 000014 (v00 BOCHS )
[    0.000000] ACPI: RSDT 0x000000007FFE1F59 000030 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCRSDT 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACP 0x000000007FFE1D79 0000F4 (v03 BOCHS  BXPCFACP 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 0x000000007FFDFCC0 0020B9 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCDSDT 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 0x000000007FFDFC80 000040
[    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 0x000000007FFE1E6D 0000B0 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCAPIC 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: MCFG 0x000000007FFE1F1D 00003C (v01 BOCHS  BXPCMCFG 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.000000] No NUMA configuration found
[    0.000000] Faking a node at [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000017fffffff]
[    0.000000] NODE_DATA(0) allocated [mem 0x17ffd5000-0x17fffffff]
[    0.000000] kvm-clock: cpu 0, msr 1:7ff54001, primary cpu clock
[    0.000000] kvm-clock: Using msrs 4b564d01 and 4b564d00
[    0.000000] kvm-clock: using sched offset of 1079516467 cycles
[    0.000000] clocksource: kvm-clock: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x1cd42e4dffb, max_idle_ns: 881590591483 ns
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000000ffffff]
[    0.000000]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000001000000-0x00000000ffffffff]
[    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000017fffffff]
[    0.000000]   Device   empty
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000009efff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000007ffd8fff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000017fffffff]
[    0.000000] Reserved but unavailable: 98 pages

[    0.951008] registered taskstats version 1
[    0.951521] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    0.953528] Loaded X.509 cert 'Build time autogenerated kernel key: 665cd2b89e03521f57c41865f552ebce30a0c7fb'
[    0.954620] zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
[    0.957486] Key type big_key registered
[    0.957917] Key type trusted registered
[    0.959363] Key type encrypted registered
[    0.959799] AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled
[    0.960446] ima: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass! (rc=-19)
[    0.961197] ima: Allocated hash algorithm: sha1
[    0.961765] evm: HMAC attrs: 0x1
[    0.962745]   Magic number: 12:440:659
[    0.963346] rtc_cmos 00:00: setting system clock to 2020-03-03 01:39:34 UTC (1583199574)
[    0.964581] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[    0.965330] EDD information not available.
[    0.967668] Freeing unused kernel image memory: 2428K
[    0.988055] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 20480k
[    0.990474] Freeing unused kernel image memory: 2008K
[    0.991305] Freeing unused kernel image memory: 1884K
[    0.996739] x86/mm: Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found.
[    0.997445] x86/mm: Checking user space page tables
[    1.002674] x86/mm: Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found.
Loading, please wait...
starting version 237
[    1.050937] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0000 32 slots 6 ports 1.5 Gbps 0x3f impl SATA mode
[    1.053041] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: flags: 64bit ncq only
[    1.060020] input: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4
[    1.060121] scsi host0: ahci
[    1.065885] input: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input3
[    1.067659] scsi host1: ahci
[    1.068632] virtio_net virtio0 enp1s0: renamed from eth0
[    1.068680] scsi host2: ahci
[    1.069944] scsi host3: ahci
[    1.070456] scsi host4: ahci
[    1.073655] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    1.074358] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[    1.075280] scsi host5: ahci
[    1.075889] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m4096@0xfde07000 port 0xfde07100 irq 37
[    1.077019] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m4096@0xfde07000 port 0xfde07180 irq 37
[    1.077988] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m4096@0xfde07000 port 0xfde07200 irq 37
[    1.078918] ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m4096@0xfde07000 port 0xfde07280 irq 37
[    1.079898] ata5: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m4096@0xfde07000 port 0xfde07300 irq 37
[    1.080776] ata6: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m4096@0xfde07000 port 0xfde07380 irq 37
[    1.392646] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    1.396850] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    1.401054] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[    1.405940] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    1.409935] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    1.413199] ata1.00: ATAPI: QEMU DVD-ROM, 2.5+, max UDMA/100
[    1.417190] ata1.00: applying bridge limits
[    1.420788] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    1.424233] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[    1.428307] scsi 0:0:0:0: CD-ROM            QEMU     QEMU DVD-ROM     2.5+ PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.435002] sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 4x/4x cd/rw xa/form2 tray
[    1.438411] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    1.440818] sr 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 5
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... [    2.728056] raid6: sse2x1   gen() 14932 MB/s
[    2.776045] raid6: sse2x1   xor() 10792 MB/s
[    2.824040] raid6: sse2x2   gen() 18419 MB/s
[    2.872044] raid6: sse2x2   xor() 12402 MB/s
[    2.920048] raid6: sse2x4   gen() 21128 MB/s
[    2.968055] raid6: sse2x4   xor() 13532 MB/s
[    3.016052] raid6: avx2x1   gen() 29495 MB/s
[    3.064054] raid6: avx2x1   xor() 20629 MB/s
[    3.112047] raid6: avx2x2   gen() 34743 MB/s
[    3.160048] raid6: avx2x2   xor() 22479 MB/s
[    3.208041] raid6: avx2x4   gen() 40986 MB/s
[    3.256054] raid6: avx2x4   xor() 24969 MB/s
[    3.256651] raid6: using algorithm avx2x4 gen() 40986 MB/s
[    3.257498] raid6: .... xor() 24969 MB/s, rmw enabled
[    3.258249] raid6: using avx2x2 recovery algorithm
[    3.259822] xor: automatically using best checksumming function   avx
[    3.261699] async_tx: api initialized (async)
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ... [    3.292295] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel
Scanning for Btrfs filesystems
[    3.300017] random: fast init done
done.
Warning: fsck not present, so skipping unknown file system
mount: can't find /root in /etc/fstab
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... mount: mounting /root/cdrom/casper/extras/modules.squashfs-generic on /root/lib/modules failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
done.
mount: mounting /run on /root/run failed: No such file or directory
run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as the root: error 0
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as the root: error 0
run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as the root: error 0
run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as the root: error 0
run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as the root: error 0
run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as the root: error 0
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.


BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.2) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

**I'm not sure what does this mean.** I tried to enter `exit`, this is what happened next:

```
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
/init: line 343: can't open /root/dev/console: no such file
[    5.089664] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100
[    5.089664]
[    5.090647] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: init Not tainted 4.15.0-76-generic #86-Ubuntu
[    5.091450] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009), BIOS 1.12.0-1 04/01/2014
[    5.092455] Call Trace:
[    5.092861]  dump_stack+0x6d/0x8e
[    5.093391]  panic+0xe4/0x254
[    5.093856]  do_exit+0xbba/0xbc0
[    5.094346]  do_group_exit+0x43/0xb0
[    5.094865]  SyS_exit_group+0x14/0x20
[    5.095403]  do_syscall_64+0x73/0x130
[    5.095944]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x3d/0xa2
[    5.096657] RIP: 0033:0x7f2ad5abfe06
[    5.097167] RSP: 002b:00007fffe2c0d6c8 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000e7
[    5.098242] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055e26f322704 RCX: 00007f2ad5abfe06
[    5.099244] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 000000000000003c RDI: 0000000000000001
[    5.100215] RBP: 00007fffe2c0db48 R08: 00000000000000e7 R09: ffffffffffffff80
[    5.100980] R10: 00000000fffffff4 R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 0000000000000004
[    5.101737] R13: 00007fffe2c0db40 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[    5.102623] Kernel Offset: 0x17e00000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[    5.103769] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100
[    5.103769]
[    5.104823] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[    5.105328] sched: Unexpected reschedule of offline CPU#2!
[    5.105923] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1 at /build/linux-xWiSio/linux-4.15.0/arch/x86/kernel/smp.c:128 native_smp_send_reschedule+0x3a/0x40
[    5.107191] Modules linked in: btrfs zstd_compress raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd cryptd psmouse glue_helper ahci virtio_net libahci virtio_blk
[    5.109734] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: init Not tainted 4.15.0-76-generic #86-Ubuntu
[    5.110492] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009), BIOS 1.12.0-1 04/01/2014
[    5.111347] RIP: 0010:native_smp_send_reschedule+0x3a/0x40
[    5.111932] RSP: 0018:ffff970dffc03e40 EFLAGS: 00010086
[    5.112489] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000002 RCX: ffffffff9a263a28
[    5.113249] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 0000000000000086 RDI: 0000000000000046
[    5.114007] RBP: ffff970dffc03e40 R08: 000000000000028f R09: 000000000000000f
[    5.114766] R10: 0000000000000004 R11: ffffffff9a75b80d R12: ffff970dffca1840
[    5.115526] R13: ffffffff9a757a80 R14: 00000000fffee004 R15: ffff970dffc1cd28
[    5.116287] FS:  00007f2ad5ff0580(0000) GS:ffff970dffc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[    5.117148] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[    5.117760] CR2: 000055e26f3260b0 CR3: 0000000143c0a003 CR4: 0000000000360ef0
[    5.118518] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[    5.119277] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[    5.120033] Call Trace:
[    5.120302]  <IRQ>
[    5.120527]  trigger_load_balance+0x166/0x270
[    5.121001]  scheduler_tick+0xae/0xd0
[    5.121398]  ? tick_sched_do_timer+0x50/0x50
[    5.121861]  update_process_times+0x47/0x60
[    5.122310]  tick_sched_handle+0x26/0x70
[    5.122733]  ? tick_sched_do_timer+0x50/0x50
[    5.123191]  tick_sched_timer+0x39/0x80
[    5.123606]  __hrtimer_run_queues+0xdf/0x230
[    5.124065]  hrtimer_interrupt+0xa0/0x1d0
[    5.124499]  smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x6f/0x140
[    5.124997]  apic_timer_interrupt+0x8c/0xa0
[    5.125446]  </IRQ>
[    5.125680] RIP: 0010:panic+0x201/0x254
[    5.126094] RSP: 0018:ffffbb6080633df8 EFLAGS: 00000282 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff11
[    5.126897] RAX: 0000000000000051 RBX: ffff970dfabc2d00 RCX: ffffffff9a263a28
[    5.127655] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000096 RDI: 0000000000000046
[    5.128414] RBP: ffffbb6080633e70 R08: 000000000000028d R09: 000000000000000f
[    5.129174] R10: ffffffff9a4600a0 R11: ffffffff9a75b86d R12: 0000000000000000
[    5.129926] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff970dfabdc6a8 R15: ffff970deff9d2f0
[    5.130681]  ? panic+0x1fa/0x254
[    5.131031]  do_exit+0xbba/0xbc0
[    5.131380]  do_group_exit+0x43/0xb0
[    5.131763]  SyS_exit_group+0x14/0x20
[    5.132154]  do_syscall_64+0x73/0x130
[    5.132549]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x3d/0xa2
[    5.133088] RIP: 0033:0x7f2ad5abfe06
[    5.133473] RSP: 002b:00007fffe2c0d6c8 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000e7
[    5.134277] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055e26f322704 RCX: 00007f2ad5abfe06
[    5.135033] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 000000000000003c RDI: 0000000000000001
[    5.135790] RBP: 00007fffe2c0db48 R08: 00000000000000e7 R09: ffffffffffffff80
[    5.136548] R10: 00000000fffffff4 R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 0000000000000004
[    5.137310] R13: 00007fffe2c0db40 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[    5.138070] Code: 8d 67 60 01 73 17 48 8b 05 44 22 16 01 be fd 00 00 00 48 8b 40 30 e8 d6 96 ba 00 5d c3 89 fe 48 c7 c7 68 01 ec 99 e8 76 62 03 00 <0f> 0b 5d c3 66 90 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 53 48 83 ec 20 65
[    5.140068] ---[ end trace 0fd048be2b983707 ]---
[    5.140567] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[    5.141068] sched: Unexpected reschedule of offline CPU#5!
[    5.141658] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1 at /build/linux-xWiSio/linux-4.15.0/arch/x86/kernel/smp.c:128 native_smp_send_reschedule+0x3a/0x40
[    5.142926] Modules linked in: btrfs zstd_compress raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd cryptd psmouse glue_helper ahci virtio_net libahci virtio_blk
[    5.145472] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: init Tainted: G        W        4.15.0-76-generic #86-Ubuntu
[    5.146366] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009), BIOS 1.12.0-1 04/01/2014
[    5.147224] RIP: 0010:native_smp_send_reschedule+0x3a/0x40
[    5.147865] RSP: 0018:ffff970dffc03de8 EFLAGS: 00010086
[    5.148428] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff970dfa4016c0 RCX: ffffffff9a263a28
[    5.149192] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 0000000000000096 RDI: 0000000000000046
[    5.149951] RBP: ffff970dffc03de8 R08: 00000000000002c5 R09: 000000000000000f
[    5.150708] R10: 0000000000000010 R11: ffffffff9a75b80d R12: ffff970dfa4021ec
[    5.151465] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000046 R15: 0000000000021840
[    5.152222] FS:  00007f2ad5ff0580(0000) GS:ffff970dffc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[    5.153082] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[    5.153696] CR2: 000055e26f3260b0 CR3: 0000000143c0a003 CR4: 0000000000360ef0
[    5.154457] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[    5.155217] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[    5.155976] Call Trace:
[    5.156246]  <IRQ>
[    5.156472]  try_to_wake_up+0x3ea/0x4a0
[    5.156888]  ? update_rq_clock+0x30/0x80
[    5.157313]  wake_up_process+0x15/0x20
[    5.157717]  swake_up_locked.part.2+0x17/0x30
[    5.158183]  swake_up+0x2c/0x40
[    5.158523]  rcu_gp_kthread_wake+0x3d/0x60
[    5.158962]  rcu_report_qs_rnp+0xf9/0x110
[    5.159391]  rcu_process_callbacks+0x45a/0x4c0
[    5.159866]  ? run_rebalance_domains+0x139/0x1f0
[    5.160359]  __do_softirq+0xe4/0x2d4
[    5.160744]  irq_exit+0xc5/0xd0
[    5.161084]  smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x79/0x140
[    5.161578]  apic_timer_interrupt+0x8c/0xa0
[    5.162027]  </IRQ>
[    5.162259] RIP: 0010:panic+0x201/0x254
[    5.162672] RSP: 0018:ffffbb6080633df8 EFLAGS: 00000282 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff11
[    5.163473] RAX: 0000000000000051 RBX: ffff970dfabc2d00 RCX: ffffffff9a263a28
[    5.164228] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000096 RDI: 0000000000000046
[    5.164989] RBP: ffffbb6080633e70 R08: 000000000000028d R09: 000000000000000f
[    5.165745] R10: ffffffff9a4600a0 R11: ffffffff9a75b86d R12: 0000000000000000
[    5.166500] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff970dfabdc6a8 R15: ffff970deff9d2f0
[    5.167257]  ? panic+0x1fa/0x254
[    5.167608]  do_exit+0xbba/0xbc0
[    5.167958]  do_group_exit+0x43/0xb0
[    5.168344]  SyS_exit_group+0x14/0x20
[    5.168739]  do_syscall_64+0x73/0x130
[    5.169137]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x3d/0xa2
[    5.169675] RIP: 0033:0x7f2ad5abfe06
[    5.170061] RSP: 002b:00007fffe2c0d6c8 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000e7
[    5.170862] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055e26f322704 RCX: 00007f2ad5abfe06
[    5.171617] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 000000000000003c RDI: 0000000000000001
[    5.172374] RBP: 00007fffe2c0db48 R08: 00000000000000e7 R09: ffffffffffffff80
[    5.173130] R10: 00000000fffffff4 R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 0000000000000004
[    5.173884] R13: 00007fffe2c0db40 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[    5.174637] Code: 8d 67 60 01 73 17 48 8b 05 44 22 16 01 be fd 00 00 00 48 8b 40 30 e8 d6 96 ba 00 5d c3 89 fe 48 c7 c7 68 01 ec 99 e8 76 62 03 00 <0f> 0b 5d c3 66 90 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 53 48 83 ec 20 65
[    5.176622] ---[ end trace 0fd048be2b983708 ]---
```

Then it stops responding. Is there anyway to install this virtual machine under command line with text UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this set of command line args,  virt-install has connected your local terminal to the guest serial port console and is printing any information that displays.

Thus you've seen the guest kernel boot messages first, which at least shows the serial console is working.

The problem you're facing is that the Ubuntu server media you are trying to install from is not using the serial console. The CD ISO name suggests that this is a "live CD" media, and its quite possible that this doesn't support text mode installs, or at least might need some extra kernel args to tell it to use console. So I'd suggest looking at what other installation media Ubuntu provide to see if one other choice is more likely to support text mode installs. Staying away from "live media" is probably a good bet.

Answer (score 0):

The ONLY way I was able to resolve this issue recently (yes, using Ubuntu 18.04) was to drag the installer from the internet, rather than using the ISO. It seems that the `initrd` that you would typically point kvm to use is present on the ISO - but it's looking for something named initrd.gz, which doesn't exist.

This is what I ended up using:

```
sudo virt-install \
--name mycoolVM \
--ram 8192 \
--disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/mycoolVM.qcow2,size=40 \
--vcpus 2 \ 
--os-variant ubuntu18.04 \
--network bridge=virbr0 \
--graphics none \
--console pty,target_type=serial \
--location http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-amd64/ \ 
--extra-args "console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial"
```

This works - but I still don't have a great solition for doing this 'offline' with an ISO.